# Calculate bearing forces

Tags: mechanical-engineering, statics

can someone tell me how to calculate the bearing forces of the two bearings?
I can't get any further because I don't have the angle for the second bearing.
I don't have an idea anymore.

F =   20KN
q0= 2000N/m
a =   1000mm

At the bottom under Lösungen are the results.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Test]

Comment: You can find the angle using trigonometry from the right angled triangle with sides a and 2a and hypotenuse along S.

Comment: Why is $M_A=0$ crossed out and replaced with $M_A=200$? The support shown in the figure is clearly a pinned support. Should that be replaced with a fixed support?

Comment: Also, is $q_0$ pushing upwards or downwards? I can't see the "arrowheads" usually drawn with distributed loads. I'm therefore assuming its upwards, since the load is given with a positive sign.

Comment: Take moments about any point, say point a and set the three equilibrium equations sum Fx= sum Fz = sum Ma=0. you don't need to know any angles.

Comment: With the trigonometric functions it does not work, because the side lengths are not a and 2a :(

Comment: @kamran So I tried, but what do I assume for the distance from the right bearing (z direction). I need it for the equation.

Comment: @B4c3z: Oh. While the horizontal measurement does seem to be "off" from the support, it seems safe to assume that's just a printing error. Or did your teacher tell you not to assume the horizontal side is equal to $a$?

Comment: @Wasabi   q0 acts downwards. Is a line load. 
The 0 was crossed out because the solution was wrong in the beginning. Ma +200NM must come out.

Comment: @Wasabi  He didn't say anything about it, but I've tried the distance a but it doesn't work. And this several times, as if I exclude a calculation error.

Comment: @B4c3z: But $M_A \ne 0$ means the support is fixed. But the figure drawn is that of a pinned support, where $M_A \equiv 0$ by definition, since it's at an extremity.

Comment: @Wasabi OK. He just said the result of MA had to be corrected to 200 KN, that the drawing was wrong, I wouldn't know.

Comment: I suggest you speak to your teacher about this exercise, since it honestly seems entirely wrong. The non-zero bending moment at a pinned support (on an extremity) is very wrong, the given vertical reaction at A is positive, indicating an upwards pushing reaction. However, this reaction should obviously be negative to counteract the "lifting" action caused by the massive distributed load at the cantilever (and the counteracting concentrated force is insufficient to overcome this). And we don't even know the angle of the diagonal member, apparently.

Comment: Also, I've modelled this in a simple structural analysis program (assuming the diagonal is indeed $2a$ high and $a$ wide) and I can't get the given results for any combination of pinned-or-fixed and orientation of forces.

Comment: @Wasabi OK, I'll talk to him about that tomorrow. Thank you very much for your help.  :)

With what kind of program can you test it?

Comment: I personally recommend [Ftool](https://www.ftool.com.br/Ftool/) (disclaimer: I was the main developer for the latest version (4.00), though I no longer work there), which has a solid free educational version and runs on your computer. Or, if you prefer something web-based, try [SkyCiv](https://skyciv.com/), though they have a (pretty low) limit to the number of nodes/bars your model can have for free.

Comment: @Wasabi Thanks alot :) The Programm Looks awesome, i will try it :)

Comment: @B4c3z IF the input is correct, and if we assume that Faz=1 kN is correct, then the vertical force in S is either 9 kN (if Faz is up) or 11 kN (if Faz is down as indicated by the axis). Either way, the force in S has to be greater than 9 kN, so the answer of 7.83 is wrong. Something is seriously wrong with the problem. Let us know what the teacher says.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions from RISA2D:

Case I - Both supports are pinned;
V(A) = 2.86 kN (pointing up),
H(A) = 15.35 kN (pointing right),
V(S) = 7.14 kN (pointing up),
H(S) = 4.649 kN

Case II - Left support pinned; right support on roller;
V(A) = 1 kN (Pointing up),
H(A) = 20 kN (pointing right),
V(S) = 9 kN (pointing up),
H(S) = 0 kN

Answer (score 0):

Lets take the moments about point a.

$ Ma = 5a*2000(4+5/2) - 20000a = 45000*a\ Nm \\  F_{vertical S}= 45000*a/5a = 9000N$

$F_{vertical}A = 10000-9000= 1000N  $

$ F_{S horizontal} = 9000*-1/2 = -4500N$

$ F_{horizonatal A}= 4500N  $

Comment: You are assuming the diagonal member has sides $a$ and $2a$, but according to the OP in the comments, that's not the case. Also, according to the results (and confirmed in the comments), $M_A = 200\text{ Nm}$, not zero (even though the drawn support at A is pinned). Therefore, none of your results match those given at the bottom of the image.

Comment: @Wasabi, I went by the diagram. I may have missed some comments. Pin support is not capable of carrying moment. I will modify my answer when I go back home.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is totally understandable, it's just apparently not the right one for the particular problem OP is having (which obviously isn't what it initially seems to be from the exercise as given).

Comment: @Kamran. Your equation for Ma has two errors: (4+5/2) should be (4a+5a/2), and it is missing the moment due to Fs.

Comment: @JohnHoltz, I don't find any errors in my answer.

Comment: @Kamran, If you are using point S in your equation for the moment about a, there are two components of Fs that you need to include. So it would be sum of moments about a is $5a*2000(4a+5a/2) - a*20000 - 5a*F_{vertical S} +2a*F_{horizontal S}=0$. Since member SC is pinned to the horizontal member, it is better to use the forces at C and write sum of moments about a is $5a*2000(4a+5a/2) - 20000a - 4a*F_{vertical C}=0$ from which $F_{vertical C}=F_{vertical S}=11250N$.

Answer (score 0):

Case I is a statically determinate system, you can get the Vertical force on support "S" by sum moments about support "A", which shall equate to zero.

Case II is statically indeterminate to the first degree. You shall conveniently release the horizontal restrain at support "S", which then becomes identical to case I. Then you have to calculate the horizontal displacement of support point "S" (d1), and apply an unit horizontal force at "S" to get an unit displacement (d2). Now you can get a new set of reactions by equating and proportioning d1 and d2 (sum displacement = 0). Finally, the reactions at supports "A" and "S" can be obtained by superposition using the two sets results. You shall review the structural analysis textbook on "solving structurally indeterminate structures by displacement method".